# Magento 2 - How to show amount "save $100 considering custom options also on detail page?

Tags: custom-options, discount, product-prices

How to show "YOU SAVE $XXX.XX" amount considering custom options (type RADIO/CHECKBOX) also on the product detail page when changing different option based on customer selection?

I have a simple product with two custom options.

1. CHECKBOX and RADIO type, both having 'Fixed' as Price Type without option level SKU.

For price and sale price, I have a code as follows.

This seems to be working fine.

```
<?php
$objectManager   = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data');
$youSave = 0.00;
$proOrgPrice = $helper->getTaxPrice($_product,$_product->getPrice(),true);
$finalPrice = $helper->getTaxPrice($_product,$_product->getFinalPrice(),true);
$youSave     = $proOrgPrice - $finalPrice;      
$price     = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');
if( $youSave > 0): 
echo 'YOU ARE SAVING:';
echo $price->currency($youSave, true, false); endif;
 ?>
```

Require to show price depends on changing of custom options at frontend.

[image]